# /bin/bash: command not found Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to run a ready project on Google Colab.. when I run a shell it gives the following error:

```
/bin/bash: example.sh: command not found
```

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two options to run shell script in `google-colab`:

1) Execute a single script with `!`:

```
!sh example.sh
!echo "I am your code !!!"
```

2) Execute entire code-block as shell script with `%%shell`:

```
%%shell
sh example.sh
echo "You should add %% "
```

**Note**: In the second approach, entire block interpreted as shell script. You do not need `!` at beginning of every script.

Comment: @noor my pleasure :)

Comment: could you please point to a resource where I can learn command usage of these shell commands in google colab!

Comment: Also, How you see the content of the files within a cell since `vi` command doesn't work?

Comment: @Amir I face a similar problem. `!make install  !gedit config.json` and I get a `/bin/bash: gedit: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me too,
After I ran the installs again the problem went away.
It turns out that every time you enter the notebook you have to do all the installations again...